# How to correctly export a rigged suspension object for use in a game engine?

Tags: armature, export, unreal-engine

I have made a simple car suspension in Blender, intended for use in Unreal Engine 5. I have built it as multiple meshes – one for each wishbone, wheel hub, damper etc., and created separate armatures for the front and rear suspensions. In order to use it in UE, I need to reduce the model to a single object with a single armature – and here comes the issue. Joining the meshes removes all bone parenting from them, as intended by Blender. Is there any way to Export the objects correctly without having to join the meshes and redo the entire armature?

For legal reasons I want to avoid posting the original file, but I might do it if strictly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Give to every bone an unique name (even if they are in different armatures), then choose one pair of rig and mesh as "Master":

Select every mesh except the Master, shift select the Master last (so it's "active", orangy outlined), Ctrl J to join them.

Do the same with the armatures (Master armature last and active).

Rename the joined armature as "Root", and you should be good to go.